# li elements wrapping even with overflow: scroll and a set width on the parent div

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why my li elements inside my div is still wrapping even though I set overflow: scroll and gave the div a width.

Here is my basic html:

```
<div id="myList">
    <ul>
        <li class="listItem"> Item 1 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </li>
        <li class="listItem"> Item 2 </li>
        <li class="listItem"> Item 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHA33/

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;` to the li css ? is that what you want? it's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I was not aware of that attribute :) Just realized that my title is very misleading. Correcting now!

Comment: well..I think it's best to first memorize all available CSS values before asking such a basic question ;) there aren't that many

Comment: I actually might, somehow, I expected a lot more properties. Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html

Comment: you just need to remember the property name, not it's value (at first) and then you can use firebug to write that property, and use the keyboard up/down keys on the value, and it will show all available values and their outcome on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Give the list **"ul"** a width: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aHA33/3/

```
#myList ul {
    width: 400px;
}

#myList
{
    border-bottom: gray 1px solid;
    border-left: gray 1px solid; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px; 
    padding-right: 0px; 
    height: 20em; 
    border-top: gray 1px solid; 
    border-right: gray 1px solid; 
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 248px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.listItem
{
    color: Navy;
    text-decoration: none! important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Arial, San-serif, Tahoma;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```